# How to get the value of the <div> element inside angular reactive form?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm using a `angular reactive` form having a text inside a div. How can i get a value of the div in my component using reactive Form Control Name is not working as it would work with `<input>` or `<select>` tag

Have tried with the code including `formcontrolname`

Html code is

```
<form [formGroup] ="groupName">
  <div formControlName = "preface">{{text}}</div>
</form>
```

```
.ts
this.groupName = this.formBuilder.group({
    preface: [null]
)}
```

I'm trying to get the value in my component using the following code

```
let text = this.groupName.get("preface").value;
```

I expect the output inside the div element to be inside the *text* variable Help!

Comment: Why are you doing this?

Comment: @Chellappan...If a scenario i want to edit the form.then i should have access to pick the previous value of the <div> element to display before it is get edited.so,may be i need to get the text of the <div> element from the form.how will i do that?

Comment: do you have stackblitz for this?

Comment: If you place formControl directive on div It will throw an error. If you want to use select Check this:https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor

Comment: @ng-suhas...No:|

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
<form [formGroup] ="groupName">
<div formGroupName="preface">{{text}}</div>
</form>
```